# Syncing Mobile Connect OptOut

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, marketing-cloud-connect

We did a mobile connect send. How ever when someone replies with STOP, they get opted out from Marketing Cloud, but the information does not pass back to Salesforce.

Please see below information:

CONTACT KEY
xxxxxxxxx

Mobile Number: xxxxx

This has unsubscribed to keyword SFMCKeyword

But still, this is not passed back to Salesforce.

The contact key is same both in Salesforce and Marketing Cloud.

Is there a way to pass back this information to Salesforce.

Please note that we are using marketing cloud connector, and email unsub get passed back to SF automatically.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported out of the box, as there isn't much functionality supported at all between MobileConnect and Salesforce.

You can try using AMPscript for this, by passing in the script to update the SF record when the automated STOP message is sent to the customer.

[UpdateSingleSalesforceObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/updatesinglesalesforceobject.htm)