# When does Mobile Opt Out field in Salesforce get updated with MobileConnect?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, marketing-cloud-connect

I have used global STOP keyword in my MC instance to opt out Contact from all keywords, as this is connected to Salesforce CRM using the MC Connector I assumed this would also check the "Mobile Opt Out" field in the related CRM record similar to email opt outs but this is not the case.

Can someone clarify if this field is actually updated and when it is updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've covered this topic few years ago in question [Syncing Mobile Connect OptOut](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/190525/syncing-mobile-connect-optout?rq=1) and unfortunately things haven't changed since then.

This field `et4ae5__HasOptedOutOfMobile__c` in Sales Cloud **isn't** supposed to be updated by a MobileConnect opt-out by default, so if this is the desired solution then you'll need to set up a custom mechanism for it.